# Graphics appearing above text

Tags: graphics, xetex, crop

For some reason the graphics is rendered above the text. I'm using xelatex (with Chinese characters).

The relevant Chinese latex compiled using `xelatex` is on `pastebin` as for some reason stackexchange won't let me post some Chinese characters.

http://pastebin.com/21uAah13

It probably has something to do with the trimming being faulty. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Removing all the other unnecessary packages, removing sections and substituting the Chinese characters with English:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}    

\begin{document}

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[trim={4cm 8cm 4cm 5.5cm},clip,height=8cm]{BotnetFamPie}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Without the `trim` and `clip`:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! A `figure` is a float. Floats are designed to float. That is, LaTeX moves them to where it thinks best. If you don't want that, don't use `figure`. Just say `\includegraphics{}`. You can get a caption using `\captionof{figure}{}` from the `caption` or `capt-of` packages.

Comment: @cfr I removed the `figure` and just used `includegraphics{}` but the graphic is still covering the text.

Comment: Don't use `\centerline`. Use `\centering` within a group or the `center` environment.

Comment: @cfr I removed the `\centerline` and it's still covering up the text.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I really think it has something to do with the trimming. I've added the English version of the same report compiled with `pdflatex` instead of `xelatex` and the relevant latex.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Changed both Chinese and English versions to be compilable.  The graphics I'm trying to include is a `png` file.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Added the minimal relevant code and screenshot.

Comment: Much better. I will delete my previous comments as this is getting so long. Please delete `hhline` as well. Try, if you get the same problem with `article`, too. If yes, change it for the MWE. If you load `\usepackage{showframe}`, you will see that your `geometry` settings are not perfect. But that is another topic.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Changing the `documentclass` to `article` and adding the `trim` and `clip` back will still have the image cover the text. I am unable to  test this with `pdflatex` as the `.tex` file is encoded in `UTF-8` which I when I try to use `pdflatex` despite the lack of Chinese characters gives me a lot of `Text line contains an invalid character.` errors.

Comment: Ok, the issue is about clipping images in XeLaTeX. You will have to use an `adjustbox` instead. Just see in the duplicate I will link to in a second. One tip for the future: when you are doing some clipping, you might want to do `\fbox{\includegraphics...}` first in order to see the actual borders of your figure. Good luck with your TeXing!